# "stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters" replaces more characters than it should

Tags: swift, cocoa, escaping

Playing around with Swift I came across something I do not understand.

The following code replaces not only the `/%` characters as intended, it also replaces the `ä` character:

```
immport Foundation

extension String{
    func encode() -> String{
        let customAllowedSet =  NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"/%").invertedSet
        return self.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(customAllowedSet)!
    }
}

let testStr = "Ein String der % und / enthält"
// contains what is expected

let percentEncodedStr = testStr.encode()
// contains "Ein String der %25 und %2F enth%C3%A4lt"

let decodedStr = percentEncodedStr.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding
// contains what was in testStr originally
```

Why is the `ä` replaced by `%C3%A4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is for encoding components or subcomponents of URLs. No non-ASCII characters are ever allowed in URLs. They are always encoded.

The [docs for `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:) say:

> Any characters in `allowedCharacters` outside of the 7-bit ASCII range are ignored.

That is, no non-ASCII characters are ever considered to be "allowed".